# SignalR Scrumboard doesn't call server-side method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am (again) trying to get a grip on to SignalR, but no matter which example im trying, it fails. This time I am dealing with [this Scrumbaord example](http://www.d80.co.uk/post/2011/10/21/SignalR.aspx).

After several failed attempts I ended up with a near 1:1 copy of the [Github](https://github.com/danswain/SignalRTutorial) code. The only changes I made was replacing Caller.populateStories and  Caller.addedStory with "Clients.Caller..." 
I constantly run into the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getStories'
```

On the following lines:

```
this.init = function () {
                   console.log("init");
                   this.hub.getStories();
               };
```

Comment: We need to see more code, can you post the full javascript and the code for the hub class that you are trying to call?

Comment: Can you verify that `'/signalr/hubs'` is actually returning the client code needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client syntax has changed since 0.5

Try

> hub.server.xxx() to call server methods

and

> hub.client.callme = functiion() { } for client callbacks

Comment: correct. As discussed on JabbR some five minutes ago. Thank you!